# How to detect if decimal columns should be converted into integer or double?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use **Apache spark** as an ETL tool to fetch tables from **Oracle** into **Elasticsearch**.

I face an issue with numeric columns that **spark** recognize them as `decimal` whereas **Elasticsearch** doesn't accept `decimal` type; so i convert each `decimal` columns into `double` which is accepted for **Elasticsearch**.

```
dataFrame = dataFrame.select(
    [col(name) if 'decimal' not in colType else col(name).cast('double') for name, colType in dataFrame.dtypes]
)
```

The current issue that every numeric column will be **double**; either it has **decimal** value or not.

My question is there any way to detect column type should be converted into either integer type or double?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to check decimals number before determine the appropriate type.

I added a function to check and return data type:

```
def check(self, colType):
    # you should import re before
    # colType will be like decimal(15,0); so get these numbers
    [digits, decimals] = re.findall(r'\d+', colType)
    # if there's no decimal points, convert it to int
    return 'int' if decimals == '0' else 'double'
```

Then i calls it for each column:

```
dataFrame = dataFrame.select(
    [col(name) if 'decimal' not in colType else col(name).cast(self.check(colType)) for name, colType in dataFrame.dtypes]
)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can retrieve all column names with datatype == **DecimalType()** from the schema of the dataframe, see below for an example (tested on Spark 2.4.0):

**Update:** just use df.dtypes which is enough to retrieve the information.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.createDataFrame([ (1, 12.3, 1.5, 'test', 13.23) ], ['i1', 'd2', 'f3', 's4', 'd5'])

df = df.withColumn('d2', col('d2').astype('decimal(10,1)')) \
       .withColumn('d5', col('d5').astype('decimal(10,2)'))
#DataFrame[i1: bigint, d2: decimal(10,1), f3: double, s4: string, d5: decimal(10,2)]

decimal_cols = [ f[0] for f in df.dtypes if f[1].startswith('decimal') ]

print(decimal_cols)
['d2', 'd5']
```

**Just a follow-up:** the above method will not work for **array**, **struct** and nested data structures. If the field names in **struct** don't contain characters like spaces, dot etc, you can use the type from the df.dtypes directly.

```
import re
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, struct, col

decimal_to_double = lambda x: re.sub(r'decimal\(\d+,\d+\)', 'double', x)

df1 = df.withColumn('a6', array('d2','d5')).withColumn('s7', struct('i1','d2'))
# DataFrame[i1: bigint, d2: decimal(10,1), l3: double, s4: string, d5: decimal(10,2), a6: array<decimal(11,2)>, s7: struct<i1:bigint,d2:decimal(10,1)>]

df1.select(*[ col(d[0]).astype(decimal_to_double(d[1])) if 'decimal' in d[1] else col(d[0]) for d in df1.dtypes ])
# DataFrame[i1: bigint, d2: double, l3: double, s4: string, d5: double, a6: array<double>, s7: struct<i1:bigint,d2:double>]
```

However, if any field-names of `StructType()` contain *spaces*, *dot* etc. the above method might not be working. In such case, I suggest you check: `df.schema.jsonValue()['fields']` to retrieve and manipulate JSON data to do the dtype transformation.

Comment: @nimeresam, I added an example for when there are array, struct (nested data types should be the same). when you can adjust the dtype with the regex. the solution you added will not handle decimal in array , struct etc.

Comment: In my case, i read an oracle table as a dataframe and try to set it as an elasticsearch index; which’s doesn’t accept decimal datatype, so i have to cast each one explicitly.

Comment: @nimeresam, my point is if there is any complex data structures (array, struct, array of structs etc) in your export, they should not be cast directly into 'double'.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html#DecimalType) `DecimalType` has parameters `precision` and `scale`. For example, in  `DecimalType(38,10)` precision=38, scale=10. We can use `scale` to differentiate Integer and Double. In particular, see below `if df.schema[col].dataType.scale > 0`

```py
decimal_cols = [ col for col in df.schema.names if isinstance(df.schema[col].dataType, DecimalType)]
cols_types = [ (col, DoubleType()) if df.schema[col].dataType.scale > 0 else (col, IntegerType()) for col in decimal_cols ]
df = df.select((F.col(c).cast(t).alias(c) for c, t in cols_types))
```

To preserve columns with other types, add `non_decimal_cols` to `SELECT`:

```py
non_decimal_cols = [ col for col in df.schema.names if not isinstance(df.schema[col].dataType, DecimalType) ]

df = df.select(*non_decimal_cols, *(F.col(c).cast(t).alias(c) for c, t in cols_types))
```